# Adding one point to a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to add a point to a plot. The plot shows the solution to Solve for different values of a parameter (a). The point that I want to add is where the parameter is zero (a=0). I know that if a->0 then [Tau]1=0.485, but I don't know why the following doesn't show this point on the graph.

```
gamma4 = .4;
gamma3 = .284;
gamma2 = .265;
gamma1 = .484;

z3 = 10000;
z2 = 32000;
z1 = 75000;
zbar4 = 4800;
zbar3 = 20050;
zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100;
h4 = .301;
h3 = .404;
h2 = .25;
h1 = .045;
p1 = 3.89;
p2 = 4.92;
p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39;
g1 = 0.00001;
g2 = 0.44;
g3 = 0.88;
g4 = 1.76;
a =.;

eq1 = (\[Tau]1/(1 - \[Tau]1)) - ((1 - 
       g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) (zbar1 - 
        z1)/((1 - ((g1 a p1/\[Tau]1) + g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
            g4 a p4)) zbar1 gamma1));
Print["0=", eq1];


sol[a_] := NSolve[{eq1 == 0  }, {\[Tau]1}, Reals][[1]]


Show[Plot[\[Tau]1 /. sol[a], {a, 0, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, \[Tau]1})], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[{0, sol[0] }]}]]
```

Thanks,

**Update:**

```
gamma4 = .4; gamma3 = .284; gamma2 = .265; gamma1 = .484; z3 = 10000; \
z2 = 32000; z1 = 75000; zbar4 = 4800; zbar3 = 20050; zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100; h4 = .301; h3 = .404; h2 = .25;
h1 = .045; p1 = 3.89; p2 = 4.92; p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39; g1 = 0.77; g2 = 0.77; g3 = 0.77;
g4 = 1.54; a =.;


eq3 = (\[Tau]3/(1 - \[Tau]3)) - (((1 - g3 - g1 h1 a p1 - g2 h2 a p2 - 
          g3 (h3 - 1) a p3 - g4 h4 a p4) h3 (zbar3 - 
          z3) + ((1 - g2 - g1 h1 a p1 - g3 h3 a p3 - 
             g4 h4 a p4) h2 + (1 - g1 - g2 h2 a p2 - g3 h3 a p3 - 
             g4 h4 a p4) h1) (z2 - z3))/((1 - g1 h1 a p1 - 
         g2 h2 a p2 - g3 a p3 (h3 + ((1 - \[Tau]3)/\[Tau]3)) - 
         g4 h4 a p4) zbar3 h3 gamma3));
Print["0=", eq3];


daSol = Solve[{eq3 == 0}, {\[Tau]3}] // Flatten // Last;
sol[aa_] := daSol /. a -> aa
t3 = Show[
  Plot[\[Tau]3 /. sol[a], {a, 0, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 11] & /@ {"Abatement \n Cost", 
       "Second Bracket"}), PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{0, \[Tau]3 /. sol[0]}]}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The plot glitch is that your `sol[0]` is returning a rule (when it works) and not a scalar.

(Also for some reason your `NSolve` seemed a little temperamental, and since eq1 is a fairly straightforward equation, I just solve analytically. )

Just use `\[Tau]1 /. sol[0]` in your `Graphics`:

```
  daSol = Solve[eq1 == 0, \[Tau]1] // Flatten // Last;
  sol[aa_] := daSol /. a -> aa  

  t3=Show[Plot[\[Tau]1 /. sol[a] // Evaluate, {a, 0, 2}, 
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {a, \[Tau]1}), 
    PlotRange -> All],  Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Blue, 
    Point[{0, \[Tau]1 /. sol[0]}]}]]
```

**Update**  As per your comment requesting a tick at $\tau_3$, to add tick marks at your favorite values on the "y" axis:

```
yTicksToAdd = {\[Tau]3 /. sol[0]};

Show[t3, bzz = 
  Ticks -> {First[Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[t3]], 
    Join[Last[
      Ticks /. 
       AbsoluteOptions[t3]], {#, 
        Style[#, {Red, 13}], {0.0375`, 0.`}, {Red, 
         AbsoluteThickness[1.5]}} & /@ (yTicksToAdd)]}]
```

Comment: Thanks @John! I have updates the codes. Is there a way I can show the number too? I mean adding a tick for that point to the existing ticks on the vertical axis. This is suggested in the forum but doesn't work: `Ticks->{Automatic,Join[Last[Ticks/.AbsoluteOptions[t3]],{{#,Style[#,\
Red,20],{0,-.02},Directive[Red,Thick]}&@{0,\[Tau]3/.sol[0]}}]}`

Comment: Some glitches in your comment code, updated my answer with something that works in V.11 for "y-axis" tick marks. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, it worked, Thanks!